# The warning message is shown while launching the media player app in Android

Tags: android

As we have developed a remote control application for car head units, we are facing the below issue while launching the app in Android 10.
Media player app is throwing the warning "This app was build for an older version of Android and may not work properly. Try checking for updates, or contact the developer." after launching the app for first time.
However the current app is target to latest API level 29 (Android 10) in `AndroidManifest.xml` and `build.gradle`

```
android:minSdkVersion="19"
android:targetSdkVersion="29"
```

What is the exact issue to throw warning even though app is targeting to latest API level.

Comment: Are you sure you have updated minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion in APK you're using? Maybe you should also check all the libraries that you're using, some of them might be outdated. Also check this article: https://www.xda-developers.com/android-q-warn-apps-target-android-lollipop/

Comment: Yes Like Micer said , Like the target and minimum could be good for Android 10 but, if you are using older libraries the error could be thrown as the libraries are not completely compatible with android 10